# Find user who have logged in from same IP

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table in SQL Server 2012, I want to find user who have logged in from same IP, for example, in my table

```
Id   UserName    IpAddress
--------------------------------
1    test        192.168.0.1
2    test1       192.168.0.5
3    test3       192.168.0.1
4    test4       192.168.0.5
5    test        192.168.0.15
6    test5       192.168.0.25
```

I want get this result

```
Id   UserName    IpAddress
1    test        192.168.0.1
2    test3       192.168.0.1
3    test1       192.168.0.5
4    test4       192.168.0.5
```

I wrote this code :

```
SELECT
    UserName, IpAddress, COUNT(*)
FROM
    UserLogin
GROUP BY
    UserName, IpAddress
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

but my result is not correct.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find user who have use same IP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35638073/find-user-who-have-use-same-ip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `OVER()`:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY IpAddress) N
    FROM dbo.YourTable
)
SELECT  Id,
        UserName,
        IpAddress
FROM CTE
WHERE N > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COUNT` with a `PARTITION BY` clause to get the number of records of each `IpAddress` slice. Then use an outer query to get `IpAddress` slices having a population that is greater than 1:

```
SELECT Id, UserName, IpAddress
FROM (
  SELECT Id, UserName, IpAddress,
         COUNT(IpAddress) OVER (PARTITION BY IpAddress) AS cnt
  FROM mytable) AS t
WHERE t.cnt > 1
```