# Find user who have use same IP

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table in SQL Server 2012, I want to find user who have logged in from same IP, for example, in my table

```
Id   UserName    IpAddress
--------------------------------
1    test        192.168.0.1
2    test1       192.168.0.5
3    test3       192.168.0.1
4    test4       192.168.0.5
5    test        192.168.0.15
6    test5       192.168.0.25
7    test        192.168.0.1
8    test        192.168.0.1
9    test        192.168.0.1
10   test3       192.168.0.1
11   test3       192.168.0.1
12   test        192.168.0.1
...  ....        ...........
```

in my query

```
SELECT Id, UserName, IpAddress
FROM (
  SELECT Id, UserName, IpAddress,
         COUNT(IpAddress) OVER (PARTITION BY IpAddress) AS cnt
  FROM UserLogin) AS t
WHERE t.cnt > 1
```

i get thi result

```
1   test    192.168.0.1            
2   test    192.168.0.1            
3   test    192.168.0.1            
4   test    192.168.0.1            
5   test    192.168.0.1           
6   test3   192.168.0.1           
7   test3   192.168.0.1            
8   test3   192.168.0.1            
9   test    192.168.0.1           
..  ....     ...
```

i want get this result

```
1   test    192.168.0.1    -- user test and user test 3 use one ip        
2   test3   192.168.0.1    -- user test and user test 3 use one ip    
3   test1   192.168.0.5    -- user test1 and user test 4 use one ip
4   test4   192.168.0.5    -- user test1 and user test 4 use one ip
..  ....     ...
```

> i want get who player that use same IP

how i can do it?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want IPs that have more than one user.  Here is one method:

```
SELECT UserName, IpAddress
FROM (SELECT UserName, IpAddress,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY IpAddress) as cnt
      FROM UserLogin
      GROUP BY UserName, IpAddress
     ) ui
WHERE cnt > 1
ORDER BY IpAddress;
```

Comment: This would not return "test1" and "test4" as OP requires.   Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @TabAlleman . . . The `COUNT(*)` is counting the number of rows that match each `IpAddress`.  It is an analytic function, not an aggregation function.  I think you are missing something.